# Magento 1: Create multiple credit memos from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, creditmemo

Is it possible to create more than one credit memo per order via Magento 1 admin?

**Example:**
I created an order with 2 products, then an invoice and then I also created one credit memo with an adjustment refund (no products refunded). After I saved the adjustment refund credit memo I'm unable to add any other additional credit memo to refund the products. Is there a hidden option to accomplish this or is it impossible by design?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should be possible. Maybe it's restricted by the used (online) payment method. You can try your self with an offline payment method like Cash On Delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is, when you create a credit memo (after creating an invoice), the order status changes to 'Closed'. You might want to use a module, or create a work-around.

Btw, It's magento, not [image] :P